# Truly Nested Components in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, components, custom-component, vue.js

Is it possible to create semantically nested elements with Vue.js?

Example: let's say I'm building an *'accordion'* element. Accordions are made up of a *'heading'* and a *'content'* section. The content can be toggled in and out of view by clicking the header. The final html for an element like this would be something like this:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="heading">
        My Accordion
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Accordions are fun! Loren ipsum dolor sit amet.
        This can be extensive text, include pictures, etc.
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to create such elements in my html using syntax like this:

```
<accordion>
    <heading>My Accordion</heading>
    <content>
        Accordions are fun! Loren ipsum dolor sit amet.
        This can be extensive text, include pictures, etc.
    </content>
</accordion>
```

The 'heading' and 'content' elements are not generic, and should only exist within the context of the parent 'accordion' element, so I believe they should be declared *within* the parent component's definition.

I know that in order to capture the innerHTML content of an element, we must use a `<slot>` element, so I tried using the following templates:

```
<template id="heading">
    <div class="heading">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="content">
    <div class="content">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion">
        <heading></heading>
        <content></content>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">

    <accordion>
        <heading>My Accordion</heading>
        <content>
           Accordions are fun. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
           I could add a lot more text here, or other elements.
        </content>
     </accordion>

</div>
```

And the Vue javascript...:

```
Vue.component('accordion', {
    template: '#accordion',
    components: {
        heading: {
            template: '#heading'
        },
        content: [
            template: '#content'
        }
    }
});

Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've read the official documentation several times, and within the *'Components'* section, when it talks about `<slot>` elements, it seems to indicate we *should* be able to do it - but I can't for the life of me work out how... The docs actually mention an element with a structure like this:

```
<app>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</app>
```

...but it doesn't give simple, concrete examples of how to do it.

The way the information is passed from parent to child element is confusing, and I have been unable to find any tutorials online that show how to setup a nested element like this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so `<heading>` and `<content>` should also be Vue components?

then it should look like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <h5>Accordion test</h5>
  <accordion>
    <heading slot="heading">Heading Text</heading>
    <content slot="content">Content Text</content>
  </accordion>

<template id="accordion">
  <div class="header">
    <slot name="heading"></slot>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <slot name="content"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="heading">
  <div class="template-heading">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="content">
  <div class="template-content">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
var Heading = Vue.extend({
  template: '#heading'
})
var Content = Vue.extend({
  template: '#content'
})
var Accordion = Vue.extend({
  template: '#accordion',
  components: {
    heading: Heading,
    content: Content
  }
})
Vue.component('heading', Heading)
Vue.component('content', Content)
Vue.component('accordion', Accordion)

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        test: 'Test'
    }
  }
})
```

So:

- The content of the `<heading>` element goes into the slot inside of 
  `<heading>`'s template.
- And the whole template of `<heading>` goes into the `<slot name="heading">`inside the template of `<accordion>`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/ud9a614o/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. There is a long discussion in the [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2507) for Vue about this issue. Your workaround is usable, but breaks the modularity of the heading and content elements, and produces unnecessarily complex and convoluted html - as noted in the discussion in the issue tracker - which is not ideal. Hopefully, that discussion will lead to this being addressed, so it will become easier to build more complex, nested elements in Vue.